# Sort test cases by number of related bugs on Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

On Azure DevOps, I have a set of test cases and every test case has a number of related bugs (from 0 to you better not know :p). The link type here is "Tests".

I would like to sort the test cases by number of related bugs, to make an estimation of the most buggy parts of the software.

I've tried but I only found the option "Number of links" ("Nombre de liens associés" in French).

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: we use Azure DevOps Server, not Azure DevOps Service. Thus, unfortunately I can't follow the steps here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/linking-attachments?view=azure-devops#list-items-based-on-linked-dependents

Comment: Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Comment: Hi Hugh, nothing new...

Answer (score 1):

> Sort test cases by number of related bugs on Azure DevOps

For this issue , I am afraid it is currently unachievable in azure devops. Currently, there is no feature of sorting by related work items in azure devops.

Running the following query in the azure devops server, you can get all test cases containing related bugs , but you cannot sort these test cases.

[image]

Apart from the negative answer, I think what you want is a good idea! So I post a feature request [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/914035/sort-test-cases-by-number-of-related-bugs-on-azure.html) in DC forum. Anyone interested in this can vote for it and track it. You could vote that suggestion ticket and share your comment there,The product team would provide the updates if they view it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that only through customization:

1. Add a new field like Bugs Count or Active Bugs count. [Add and manage fields for an inherited process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/customize-process-field?view=azure-devops)
2. Create custom app to fill that field with real count of bugs through REST API. [Wiql - Query By Wiql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/wiql/query%20by%20wiql?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1), [Work Items - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)
3. Then you can use a column setting to edit the sort order of your query result.

Comment: Thank you Shamrai, I will have a look! Thanks!